# Retrieve task specific to user from outlook using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, office-interop

I'm using the below code to fetch tasks from `Outlook 2007`.

```
    public class c_tasks : IDisposable
    {
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = null;
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace objNamespace = null;
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder objFolder = null;
        private string strType; // this is type "Tasks"
        private int iItemCounter;

        public c_tasks()
        {
            objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
            objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            strType = "Tasks";
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (objOutlook != null) objOutlook.Quit();
        }

        public void iGetAllTaskItems()
        {
            int iReturn = 0;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TaskItem item;

            try
            {
                objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
                item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TaskItem)objFolder.Items[1];
                for (int ii = 2; ii <= objFolder.Items.Count; ii++)
                {
                    string sub = item.Subject;
                    string own = item.Owner;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {

            }
            return iReturn;
        }
    }
```

It works fine and I'm getting a result. But suppose I have `2 Users` in the Outlook data. How do you retrieve tasks specific to a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

1. Bind Using = `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`
2. Create the List = `public static List<Outlook.TaskItem> Aufgaben = new List<Outlook.TaskItem>();`
3. Take my code

   ```
        Outlook.MAPIFolder task = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
       foreach (Outlook.TaskItem task2 in task.Items)
       {
           //MessageBox.Show(task2.ConversationTopic);
           Aufgaben.Add(task2);
       }
   ```
4. Be happy :D

Answer (score 0):

Your program will be running under some user's credentials. When you make the call to GetDefaultFolder, it retrieves that user's tasks.

In order to retrieve another user's tasks, you have to call [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575.aspx), and the current user has to have permission to open that shared folder. Pay attention to the Remarks section of the GetSharedDefaultFolder link, there are some special folders you can't access with that method.